# Delete posts with word count less than x number of words

Tags: mysql, sql

I searched a lot about this, found plugins that are out dated and consumes massive resources and finally do nothing, is there like an SQL line to delete all posts that have a word count like less than 100 words?

Thanks,

Comment: Counting words with SQL isn't so easy. The problem is that it's pretty hard to define what a word is, so that MySQL can understand it. For example there are special strings that are spaces (`&nbsp;`) and can be used as word separators... Also you can have HTML tags inside your content - how should that be counted?

Comment: may be character length? in average the word is 5 characters or so, so can we delete using sql posts with length below 500 or 600 characters (inculding spaces for example)?

Answer (score -1):

```
function delete_posts() {
$lastposts = get_posts(array('numberposts' => -1));

if ( $lastposts ) {
    foreach ( $lastposts as $post ) :
        setup_postdata( $post ); ?>        
        <?php
        $content = get_the_content();
        if (str_word_count($content) < 100) {   
            wp_trash_post($post->ID);
        }

        ?>
        <?php
    endforeach; 
    wp_reset_postdata();
}}add_action( 'init', 'delete_posts' );
```

Comment: this caused fatal error Fatal error: Allowed memory size  exhausted (tried to allocate 84 bytes) /.../wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1889

Comment: Two way  - 1. Use below code into wp-config.php file
`define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');`

2. Edit your PHP.ini file
`memory_limit = 256M;`

Comment: but this i think will cause server to crash, I had a load surge even at the previous limit!